# PJSIP Error building for x86

Tags: x86, makefile, sip, pjsip, portaudio

Hello fellow developers,

I have successfully built for armeabi-v7a, armeabi...
And when I am trying to build PJSIP for x86 ABI using:

```
TARGET_ABI=x86 ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags --with-openh264=/root/openh264-x86 --with-libyuv=/root/libyuv-x86/jni --with-ssl=/root/openssl-x86
make dep && make
```

I am getting errors:

```
make[3]: *** [output/libportaudio-x86-unknown-none/pa_unix_util.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/pjproject-x86/third_party/build/portaudio'
make[2]: *** [libportaudio-x86-unknown-none.a] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/pjproject-x86/third_party/build/portaudio'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/pjproject-x86/third_party/build'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

[Full error log](http://pastie.org/10631957)

Where and What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the reason of using PortAudio ? you can disable it and use ALSA which is a part of Linux kernel

Comment: I think it is default configuration... where I can disable it? Will it be a problem? if I have built armeabi and armeabi-v7a with port audio and x86 with ALSA...

Comment: Add #define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_PORTAUDIO 0
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_ALSA 1   in the config_site.h file

Comment: thanks @azimov Will it be a problem? if I have built armeabi and armeabi-v7a with port audio and x86 with ALSA

Comment: no, it won't. You build for x86 which creates separated libs;

Comment: @azimov I added following lines
#define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_PORTAUDIO 0
#define PJMEDIA_AUDIO_DEV_HAS_ALSA 1

but error is still there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved issue, using ready "script"..

[pjsip-android-builder](https://github.com/alexbbb/pjsip-android-builder)

Simply follow the instructions :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try the fix for this for 2.5: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/changeset/5213